# Django query optimization: retrieve values in groups possible?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have:

```
active = Node.objects.filter(status = 'a')
potential = Node.objects.filter(status = 'p')
hotspot = Node.objects.filter(status = 'h')
```

I'm wondering: is it's possible to do it in a better way?

EDIT: maybe i didn't explain myself very well. I need to have 3 lists with the 3 different status. If I do just 1 query then I will have to loop over the list to make 3 new lists, but if the list if very long wouldn't that be inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better, use `in`:

```
Node.objects.filter(status__in=['a', 'p', 'h'])
```

**Edit after comment** Don't know why that would be inefficient. Perhaps one improvement would be to add `.order_by('status')` so you get an ordered queryset, then split when you iterate through. Likely to be a micro-optimization though.

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself very well. I need to have 3 lists with the 3 different status. If I do just 1 query then I will have to loop over the list to make 3 new lists, but if the list if very long wouldn't that be inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Django Q objects

`from django.db.models import Q;`

`Node.objects.filter(Q(status = 'a') | Q(status = 'p' | Q(status = 'h'))`

Source: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects